# Autoload PHPExcel library with Yii (include(PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

I'm using **Yii framework** , and I have to load **PHPExcel**  classes.

in my main.php I set the configuration as

```
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
                'application.extensions.*',
                'ext.PHPExcel.PHPExcel',            
    ),
```

in I was edit the Register function inside  **Autoloader.php** as follow

```
public static function Register() {
        $functions = spl_autoload_functions();

          foreach($functions as $function)
            spl_autoload_unregister($function);
          $functions=array_merge(array(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load')), $functions);

          foreach($functions as $function)
            $x = spl_autoload_register($function);
          return $x;
  }
```

when I call `$objPHPExcel =new PHPExcel();` it's  working well,

but when I call `$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();` its return

```
include(PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

my directory structure is :

```
extensions
    -----PHPExcel
          -------PHPExcel
    ------ PHPExcel.php
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code out if it works, notice there are dual `*`

```
Yii::import('ext.PHPExcel.**', true); 

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
var_dump($objDrawing);
```

[Tested in Yii version: 1.1.13]

Answer (score 0):

this module worked for me initially. but then I added Yii2 and spent a long time looking for a solution to the problem. for those who find this topic, as I did and also added Yii2 to Yii1, I will leave this solution.

for me first helped this.

```
        spl_autoload_unregister(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
        require_once Yii::app()->params['rootPath'] . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
        spl_autoload_register(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
```

when i added Yii2 i changed

```
        spl_autoload_unregister(['Yii', 'autoload']);
        spl_autoload_unregister(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
        require_once Yii::app()->params['rootPath'] . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
        spl_autoload_register(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
        spl_autoload_register(['Yii', 'autoload']);
```

and use

```
  $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
```